# CSS hover effect on rotating div

Tags: css, sass

I have div which I'm continuously rotating using transform rotate (which is working). I then want to be able to scale the div when I hover over the rotating div. I can't get this to work, it does scale when I remove the rotation but I want it to rotate and then scale on hover.

Here is a demo pen i have created: (I'm using sass)

http://codepen.io/HJBdev/pen/BWVMjZ

```
<div class="spin">

</div>

.spin {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: rotation 7s infinite linear;
  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are overriding your `transform` style with that `:hover`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a container div to Re-scale on hover, then make the .spin div 100%

Like so:


HTML:

```css
    .cont {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    .cont:hover {
      height: 75px;
      width: 75px;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    .spin {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: red;
      -webkit-animation: rotation 7s infinite linear;
      &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.3);
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="spin">
      
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tip: to the right of the image button there is a snippet button where you can insert your HTML and CSS to create an executable demo and you don't have to separate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new animation for the hover that includes the `scale`.

Like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotationScale {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg) scale(1.3);
  }
}
```

Then just use it instead on hover:

```
.spin {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: rotation 7s infinite linear;

  &:hover {
    -webkit-animation: rotationScale 7s infinite linear;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without adding any more HTML elements or a wrapper for them, you can use this CSS. And it maybe worth noting that the transition effect makes it more visually appealing to the user because it changes over a chosen duration rather than trying to change in an instant.

```
.spin {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation: rotation 7s infinite linear;
    transition:height 1.5s, width 1.5s;
    &:hover {
        height:8em;
        width:8em;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```